# How to remove $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] from a given string in PHP

Tags: php, string, oop

How can i remove `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from a string like this 
/home/bla/test/pic/photo.jpg

the result should look like this
/test/pic/photo.jpg

I also need to take the photo.jpg from /test/pic/photo.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your DocumentRoot corresponds to the portion of the string you want to remove, a solution could be to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) :

```
echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', '/home/bla/test/pic/photo.jpg');
```

But note that you'll run into troubles in the content of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is present somewhere else in your string : it will be removed, each time.

If you want to make sure it's only removed from the beginning of the string, a solution could be to use some regex :

```
$docroot = '/home/bla';
$path = '/home/bla/test/pic/photo.jpg';
echo preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($docroot, '/') . '/', '', $path);
```

Note the `^` at the beginning of the regex *(to indicate that it should only match at the beginning of the string)* -- and don't forget to escape the special characters from your document root, using [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/preg_quote).

And to get the name of a file when you have a path containing directory + name, you can use the [`basename`][3] function ; for instance, this portion of code :

```
echo basename('/test/pic/photo.jpg');
```

Will give you this output :

```
photo.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_string = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $string);
$photo = basename($string);
```

Links:
- http://de.php.net/str_replace
- http://de.php.net/basename

Answer (score 0):

.........

```
echo basename(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', '/home/bla/test/pic/photo.jpg'));

// output: photo.jpg
```